# How can I reset CVAT to a clean state?

Tags: cvat

I have an old installation of CVAT on a server which does not run - `cvat_server` restarts constantly - and I would like to reset it to a clean state.

Steps taken:

- `docker image rm` for all the images referred to by docker-compose.yml
- `docker volume rm` for all cvat_cvat_* volumes listed

Restarting with `docker compose up -d` (which reloads the images) leads to same problem as before with `cvat_server` constantly restarting.

How can I reset this instance?